# Consulta en SQL Server sin "WHERE"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy creando algunos reportes y realmente no tengo problema con la consulta siguiente, como podrán ver es sencilla y se ejecuta bien pero me di cuenta que **olvide** poner el "`where`" y aún así funciona correctamente; nunca había visto algo parecido; me gustaría saber **¿cual es la razón por la que se ejecuta correctamente?**, lo que pensé en primer momento es que el `on` funciono de cierta manera como un un `where`. pero no estoy seguro.

```
select nodo1.*,tareas.nombre_flujo,tareas.descripcion_tarea+' '+tareas.anexo1
    from(   
        select pren.linea, pren.orden, pren.tipo_cambio,pren.fecha_inicio,pren.noun,detalle.id_tarea
        from mecaprensa as pren inner join control_tareas_flujo_produccion as detalle on (pren.id_mecaprensa=detalle.id_documento)
        and pren.orden like '00015'
    ) as nodo1 inner join desc_tarea as tareas on (tareas.no_tarea=nodo1.id_tarea)
    ORDER BY termino
```

Nota: *muchos buscan respuestas solo cuando algo no sale bien, pero esto me da curiosidad, puede que se pueda utilizar estratégicamente en otras consultas*.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres que funciona sin el where? Porque toda consulta funciona sin una condición, la diferencia radica en el resultado obtenido

Comment: en mi primer consulta, después inner join, agrego una "condición"  `pre.orden like '00015'`

Comment: No entiendo bien a que te refieres, puedo observar que tu JOIN lo haces sobre dos campos.

Comment: y cual se supondría sería la condición que vas a colocar en el where?

Comment: En los joins tambien puedes agregar condiciones sobre las tablas que estas relacionando, en este caso le estas diciendo desde el join que te haga un like en ese preciso momento que se ejecuta la relacion, por eso te funciona como un filtro.

Comment: Puede que funcione porque todas tus columnas `orden` cumplen la condición del `LIKE` al menos en ese `JOIN`. Si al menos una columna `orden` tuviera un valor como `00017` seguro que no te la va a traer. De todos modos, el filtro del `WHERE` es mejor ponerlo aparte, no en el `JOIN`.

Comment: eso es lo que me imaginaba @ErickSoto, entonces mi consulta en realidad esta aplicando la condición directamente en inner join; más no en mi consulta "global" por llamarlo de alguna manera

Comment: Estas haciendo un select del resultado previo que obtuviste, te va a traer todos los registros que cumplan con el inner join

Answer (score -1):

Eso es porque ya estás agregando una condición específica dentro del `JOIN`, pero con eso estás haciendo que la consulta solamente te muestre (**SIEMPRE**) la misma información, en tu caso, todo lo relacionado con la `pren.orden = '00015'`

Comment: gracias, de momento estaba haciendo consultas especificas, el '00015' lo cambiaré por una variable posteriormente.

Comment: pero, el where en el JOIN, ¿puede afectar en algo si lo dejo así? o debo agregar mi where fuera del join.

Comment: Si, te afectará, lo mejor sea que los joins los hagas exclusivamente sobre los campos relaciondos de ambas tablas y que con el WHERE manipules el filtro, así sea que uses una variable o no. Es más manejable de esa manera, además de ser la solución más aceptada en lo que a programación se refiere.